# PHP web extracted string broken encoding

Tags: php, encoding, preg-match, domxpath

I have a problem with converting string encoding for preg_match. I have a source page in windows-1250.

I am using DOMDocument and XPath to get this text:
**"Nabídkový katalog na aukci dne 8. června 2014"**

Tried many ways and wasn't able to produce this output to be on input of preg_match. I want to extract date from this string. preg_match is not able to work properly with multibyte characters.

Best result was:

```
echo 'htmlentities: ' . htmlentities($string) . "<br>\n";
// htmlentities: Nabídkový katalog na aukci dne 8. ÄŤervna 2014
```

I think one character encoding is broken, but it will appear correctly when viewed by web browser.

I could do something like this:

```
$a = array('ÄŤ' => 'č');
```

But I need an universal solution.

Here is my test code:

```
$url = 'http://numismatika.cz/web/Nummus-Praha/U064_Katalog/obsah.htm';
// <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250" />

$xpath = '/html/body/table//tr/td[2]/p[2]/font';

$html = @file_get_contents($url, FALSE);
if ($html === FALSE) {
    throw new Exception($url);
}

$domDocument = new \DOMDocument();
if (!@$domDocument->loadHTML($html)) {
    throw new Exception($url);
}

$domXpath = new \DOMXPath($domDocument);

$element = $domXpath->query($xpath);
if (isset($element->item(0)->textContent)) {

    $string = $element->item(0)->textContent;

    // Expected output: "Nabídkový katalog na aukci dne 8. června 2014"

    echo 'Original: ' . $string . "<br>\n";
    // Original: NabĂ­dkovĂ˝ katalog na aukci dne 8. ÄŤervna 2014

    echo 'utf8_decode: ' . utf8_decode($string) . "<br>\n";
    // utf8_decode: Nabídkový katalog na aukci dne 8. ?ervna 2014

    echo 'iconv (windows-1250 to ISO-8859-1): ' . iconv('windows-1250', 'ISO-8859-1', $string) . "<br>\n";
    // Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in C:\xampp\htdocs\testDateExtract.php on line 37
    // iconv (windows-1250 to ISO-8859-1):

    echo 'iconv (windows-1250 to ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT): ' . iconv('windows-1250', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $string) . "<br>\n";
    // iconv (windows-1250 to ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT): NabA­dkovA" katalog na aukci dne 8. ÄTervna 2014

    echo 'iconv (windows-1250 to ISO-8859-1//IGNORE): ' . iconv('windows-1250', 'ISO-8859-1//IGNORE', $string) . "<br>\n";
    // iconv (windows-1250 to ISO-8859-1//IGNORE): Nab­dkov katalog na aukci dne 8. Äervna 2014

    echo 'iconv (windows-1250 to ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE): ' . iconv('windows-1250', 'ISO-8859-1//IGNORE', $string) . "<br>\n";
    // iconv (windows-1250 to ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE): Nab­dkov katalog na aukci dne 8. Äervna 2014

    echo 'iconv (windows-1250 to ASCII): ' . iconv('windows-1250', 'ASCII', $string) . "<br>\n";
    // Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in C:\xampp\htdocs\testDateExtract.php on line 56
    // iconv (windows-1250 to ASCII):

    echo 'iconv (windows-1250 to ASCII//TRANSLIT): ' . iconv('windows-1250', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string) . "<br>\n";
    // iconv (windows-1250 to ASCII//TRANSLIT): NabA-dkovA" katalog na aukci dne 8. "ATervna 2014

    echo 'iconv (windows-1250 to ASCII//IGNORE): ' . iconv('windows-1250', 'ASCII//IGNORE', $string) . "<br>\n";
    // iconv (windows-1250 to ASCII//IGNORE): Nabdkov katalog na aukci dne 8. ervna 2014

    echo 'iconv (windows-1250 to ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE): ' . iconv('windows-1250', 'ASCII//IGNORE', $string) . "<br>\n";
    // iconv (windows-1250 to ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE): Nabdkov katalog na aukci dne 8. ervna 2014

    echo 'iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", utf8_encode($string)): ' . iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', utf8_encode($string)) . "<br>\n";
    // Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in C:\xampp\htdocs\testDateExtract.php on line 71
    // iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", utf8_encode($string)):

    echo 'htmlentities: ' . htmlentities($string) . "<br>\n";
    // htmlentities: Nabídkový katalog na aukci dne 8. ÄŤervna 2014

    echo 'htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlentities($string), ENT_COMPAT): ' . htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlentities($string), ENT_COMPAT) . "<br>\n";
    // htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlentities($string), ENT_COMPAT): Nabídkový katalog na aukci dne 8. ÄŤervna 2014

    $regex = '([0-9]{1,2})[.]?[\s]*([0-9a-zúřěčáí]+)[.]?[\s]*([0-9]{4})';
    echo 'preg_match /([0-9]{1,2})[.]?[\s]*([0-9a-zúřěčáí]+)[.]?[\s]*([0-9]{4})/: ' . preg_match('/' . $regex . '/', $string, $matches) . "<br>\n";
    // preg_match /([0-9]{1,2})[.]?[\s]*([0-9a-zúřěčáí]+)[.]?[\s]*([0-9]{4})/: 0

    $regex = '([\p{N}]{1,2})[.]?[\S]*([\p{N}\p{L}]+)[.]?[\S]*([\p{N}]{4})';
    echo 'preg_match /([\p{N}]{1,2})[.]?[\S]*([\p{N}\p{L}]+)[.]?[\S]*([\p{N}]{4})/u: ' . preg_match('/' . $regex . '/u', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) . "<br>\n";
    // preg_match /([\p{N}]{1,2})[.]?[\S]*([\p{N}\p{L}]+)[.]?[\S]*([\p{N}]{4})/u: 0
}
```

Comment: Try to add a meta tag with the current charset: `if (!@$domDocument->loadHTML('<meta charset="Windows-1250">'. $html)) {`

Comment: Are you outputing "**Nabídkový katalog na aukci dne 8. června 2014**" to a file or reading on a browser ?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and output `$string` on a browser and it displayed correctly.
My guess is that `file_get_contents` is breaking the utf-8 encoding

You may want to try this:

```
// Tell PHP that we're using UTF-8 strings until the end of the script
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

// Tell PHP that we'll be outputting UTF-8 to the browser
mb_http_output('UTF-8');


$string = $element->item(0)->textContent;
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
```

If you want to output the result to a browser you should set the correct header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```